# How do I count the amount of students being taught per instructor without duplicates being included?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I was given a database that has the following 3 tables:

```
instructor(ID, name, dept_name, salary)
teaches(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
takes(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
```

The goal of the query is to count the total amount of students taught by each teacher, but each student can only be counted one time per teacher. My problem is right now that teachers that teach zero students do not get included.

An example output that I would want is something like this:

```
dept_name   id      ins_name  students_taught
Accounting  79081   Ullman    1218
Accounting  14365   Lembr     529
Accounting  77645   Jarold    0
Astronomy   43779   Romero    981
Athletics   41930   Tung      749
Athletics   63287   Jaekel    524
Athletics   15347   Bawa      266
Athletics   76458   Smith     0
Biology     81991   Valtchev  550
Biology     80759   Queiroz   312
Biology     98738   Quincy    0
Biology     22213   Lee       0
Comp. Sci.  34175   Bondi     817
Comp. Sci.  3335    Bourrier  566
```

But the problem is I get this instead:

```
dept_name   id      name     students_taught
Accounting  79081   Ullman   1218
Accounting  14365   Lembr    529
Astronomy   43779   Romero   981
Athletics   41930   Tung     749
Athletics   63287   Jaekel   524
Athletics   15347   Bawa     266
Biology     81991   Valtchev 550
Biology     80759   Queiroz  312
Comp. Sci.  34175   Bondi    817
Comp. Sci.  3335    Bourrier 566
```

I have tried many different ways to do this like using where clauses or using left joins but the result is always the same. Is there something I am missing?

For reference here are two different attempts I have made at this problem:

```
Attempt 1:
SELECT instructor.dept_name AS dept_name,
       instructor.id AS inID,
       instructor.name AS name,
       count(DISTINCT takes.id) AS total
FROM instructor
LEFT OUTER JOIN teaches ON instructor.id = teaches.id
JOIN
  (SELECT dept_name,
          id,
          name
   FROM instructor) AS ins,
     takes
WHERE takes.course_id = teaches.course_id
  AND takes.sec_id = teaches.sec_id
GROUP BY inID
ORDER BY dept_name,
         total DESC;

Attempt 2:
SELECT instructor.dept_name AS dept_name,
       instructor.id,
       instructor.name,
       count(DISTINCT takes.id) AS total
FROM instructor
INNER JOIN teaches ON teaches.id = instructor.id
INNER JOIN takes ON takes.course_id = teaches.course_id
AND takes.sec_id = teaches.sec_id
GROUP BY ins.id
ORDER BY dept_name,
         total DESC;
```

Comment: I don't see an instructor id in the other two tables, so I don't see how they are related.

Comment: Don't mix implicit ("comma") and expicit(JOIN) join notation... generally, avoid comma joins entirely; and what is the intent of having that subquery in attempt 1?

Comment: @GordonLinoff According to his 2nd attempt, I think the Teaches.ID and Instructor.ID are the same.

Comment: @Uueerdo I was honestly just spitballing ideas and seeing what worked no matter how weird they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note @GordonLinoff comment in the original post. I assuming that the Teaches.ID = Instructor.ID, as in attempt # 2. If I am assuming wrong, then there is no relationship, and thus you can not get the results your looking for.

You are pretty close with your second attempt. The mistake in the group by statement

```
SELECT a.dept_name
    ,a.ID
    ,a.NAME
    ,count(DISTINCT c.ID) AS Total
 FROM instructor a
 LEFT JOIN teaches b ON b.ID = a.ID
 LEFT JOIN takes c ON c.course_id = b.course_id
    AND c.sec_id = b.sec_id
GROUP BY a.dept_name
    ,a.ID
    ,a.NAME
```

I tested this using some sample data and it worked perfectly fine.

Sample Data

Here is the Raw data. Note how that one professor has a student in more than 1 class.
Also note that I had a student listed twice in the same class for testing purposes.

```
ID  name    dept_name   salary  ID  course_id   sec_id  semester    year    ID  course_id   sec_id  semester    year    grade
79081   Ullman  Accounting  100 79081   1   2   1   2019    13  1   2   1   2019    12
14365   Lembr   Accounting  100 14365   2   2   1   2019    14  2   2   1   2019    12
14365   Lembr   Accounting  100 14365   2   2   1   2019    14  2   2   1   2019    12
77645   Jarold  Accounting  100 77645   3   2   1   2019    10  3   2   1   2019    12
77645   Jarold  Accounting  100 77645   3   2   1   2019    11  3   2   1   2019    12
77645   Jarold  Accounting  100 77645   3   2   1   2019    12  3   2   1   2019    12
77645   Jarold  Accounting  100 77645   4   2   1   2019    10  4   2   1   2019    12
```

here are the results

```
dept_name   ID  NAME    Total
Accounting  14365   Lembr   1
Accounting  77645   Jarold  3
Accounting  79081   Ullman  1
```

I hope this helps!! Good Luck!

Comment: Oh sorry about that I should have specified which IDs were equal. I'll test your solution when I get home and update you.